# Control from the User control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

Am using the [intellibox](https://intellibox.codeplex.com/) from codeplex to create custom picker

and i created my own custom control using those binaries. but how ever it throws some exception while initialization

Original Control project

[image: Control]

**My inherited Custom Control code**

```
namespace Apico.Controls
{
    public class PushItemsPicker : Intellibox
    {
        public PushItemsPicker()
        {
            this.DataProvider = new PushItemsDataProvider();
        }
    }

    public class DocumentListPicker : Intellibox
    {
        public DocumentListPicker()
        {            
            this.DataProvider = new DocumentListDataProvider();
        }
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
{"The component 'Apico.Controls.DocumentListPicker' does not have a resource identified by the URI '/Intellibox;component/intellibox.xaml'."}
{"'The invocation of the constructor on type 'Apico.Controls.DocumentListPicker' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '132' and line position '10'."}
```

**Workaround**

I have tried adding that usercontrol(Intellibox.xaml) in the resource dictionary, it doesn't help, because its an user control,and i aware i cant add this into resource dictionary.

```
 <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>               
           <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes.xaml"/>
          <ResourceDictionary Source= "/Intellibox;component/Intellibox.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

is there any other way to do a control like above, or am i correct inhering the control to my own custom control am i missing anything??

Comment: "Custom Control" is a specific template, did you really use that? Show a small sample project with your PushItemsPicker.

Comment: @HenkHolterman yes, you are correct, but here its not a custom control, just a class library inherited from the intellibox, and am using it in WPF prjects

Comment: Maybe inheriting from a UserControl (/Window/Page) is not so easy as that.